# Mongoose - pull x number of objects from array and use x to update another field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Basically I would like to pull x amount of objects from an array and use that x amount to update another field within the same query like below

```
export const publicTaskSchema = new Schema({
  likes: {
    likes: { required: false, type: Number, default: 0 },
    users: { required: false, type: [profileSchema], default: [] },
  },
 })

export const publicTaskListSchema = new Schema({
  tasks: { required: true, type: [publicTaskSchema], default: null },
});
```

```
  const PublicTaskList = model("publicTaskList");

  await PublicTaskList.updateMany(
    {},
    {
      
     // if this pulls two objects

      $pull: {
        "tasks.$[].likes.users": {
          "user._user": req.user?._user,
        },
       
      //  decrement the following field by 2

       $inc: { tasks.$[].likes.likes: /* returned number from above */ }
      },
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option via aggregate framework:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
 $match: {
  "likes.users": {
    $in: [
      "user1",
      "user2"
     ]
   }
  }
 },
{
 "$addFields": {
  "afterRemoval": {
    "$setDifference": [
      "$likes.users",
      [
        "user1",
        "user2"
      ]
     ]
    }
   }
  },
 {
 "$addFields": {
   "afterRemovalCount": {
     $size: "$afterRemoval"
   }
  }
},
{
 "$project": {
  "likes": {
    likes: "$afterRemovalCount",
    users: "$afterRemoval"
   }
  }
 },
 {
"$merge": {
  "into": "collection",
  "on": "_id",
  "whenMatched": "replace",
  "whenNotMatched": "discard"
   }
  }
])
```

Explanation:

1. **$match** documents having at least one of users
2. **$addFields** "afterRemoval" having the users removed
3. **$addFileds** "afrerRemovalCount" having the count of users after removal
4. **$project** the likes filed with the new users + likes
5. **$merge** to the original collection the modified documents.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ezzbNj7kfx4)